# How to echo backslash then quote?

Tags: php, echo

I want to echo `\"` and am trying this code:

```
echo '\"'
```

but this will just output `"`

I tried `&#92;` but it just outputs `&#92;`.

Comment: http://www.google.com/m?q=php%20escape%20characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding echo to a variable `$text`, if this is in javascript then you should echo the value using php in your javascript - like this var `test=<?php echo $test; ?>`. If you are using php then you should try implementing @Guilherme Nascimento's answer, but concatanating not adding echo to your `$text` variable. So you should have something like this:

```
    $text='<p align="center">
<iframe src="aufgaben".$_COOKIE["auf_name"]."/".$_COOKIE["auf_name"].".html" width="322" height="497" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>';
```

By using the `'` in echo you escape the `"` character

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
 `echo '\\"';`

Full code:

```
$text = '<?php echo \'<p align="center"><iframe src="aufgaben/'.$_COOKIE['auf_name'].'/'.$_COOKIE['auf_name'].'.html" width="322" height="497" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>\'; ?>';
```

Read this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Answer (score 1):

The `\` escapes the `"` from ending a string, and thus only the `"` is read. Double the backslash and it'll work:

`echo '\\"';`

Demo: http://codepad.org/ndGeFl8H

Comment: it didn't work for me here's the complete code:
 
    $text = "<"."?"."php echo \"<p align=&#92;\"center\"><iframe src=\"aufgaben/".$_COOKIE["auf_name"]."/".$_COOKIE["auf_name"].".html\" width=\"322\" height=\"497\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></p>\"; "."?".">";

Comment: at the place of & #92; I tried to replace it with an extra \ but it didn't work

Comment: the $text string is in php but its added then to a part of a js

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/20927684/1518921

Answer (score 0):

The "\" backslash symbol escapes a character that can end a string usually used to escape a single or double speech mark.

```
<?php 

      echo '\\"';

?>
```

EDIT: I saw your comment where your having issues with the code after trying a similar suggestion as mine... Try this:

```
$text = "<p align=\"center\"><iframe src=\"aufgaben/".$_COOKIE["auf_name"]."/".$_COOKIE["auf_name"].".html\" width=\"322\" height=\"497\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></p>";
echo $text;
```